# RxJava: Watch custom class

Tags: java, event-handling, rx-java

I have a custom class, call it `Builder`.  It has a method `act()`, that performs an async operation.  When the operation is done, I want to emit an event.

How can I accomplish this in RxJava?

Seems like a straightforward task, but I have yet to see the right RxJava way to do it.

For more detail, a typical `act()` method looks like so:

```
    class Builder
       public void act() {
            processRunner.runAsync(new ProcessRunner.ProcessResultHandler(){
                @Override
                public void onComplete(int result) {
                    // Emit event
                }
            });
        }
```

And what I want is in the consuming class, to call:

```
builder.act()
```

And somehow be alerted to when `onComplete()` is called.

---

I also control `ProcessRunner`, so I'd like to convert that to RxJava and chain results, but for now I'll take the simple usecase!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can possible using **PublishSubject** in RxJava.  Let me explain to you how you can use it into your builder. Create the class as shown below:

```
public class Communicator {
  private static Communicator  mCommunicator = new Communicator();
  private PublishSubject<Void> mGrabEvent = new PublishSubjetct.create();
  private Communicator(){
  }
  public static getCommunicator(){
   return mCommunicator
  }
  public static emitEventItem(){
     // you can pass any object that you want to listen
     mGrabEvent.onNext(null);
  }
 public PublishSubject<Void> subscribeEvent(){
   return mGrabEvent;
 }
}
```

This class would help you to emit & subscribe it for listening to that particular event anywhere into your application. Below I try to show you how to emit and hook that listener into you activity or fragment.

A. For emit the message from your builder class

```
class Builder{
  public void act() {
    processRunner.runAsync(new ProcessRunner.ProcessResultHandler(){
      @Override
      public void onComplete(int result) {
        // Emit event
        Communicatort.getCommunicator().emitEventItem();
      }
    });
  }
  }
```

B. Another end point where you would listen to it by subscribing it.

```
Communicatort.getCommunicator().subscribeEvent().subscribe(new Action<Void>(){
  @overrider
  public void call(Void void){
  }
});
```

C. In last, Make sure you should unsubscribe it onDestroy of the activity.

I hope that could help you. Let me know if you could understand in any point.

Thanks,
Bhavdip

Comment: PublishSubject is how I ended up doing this one, but I put it on the Builder class itself.  Thanks for the extra info, it looks like a nice approach!

Comment: Just keep in mind that Subjects are "Hot Observables" which means it can emit items even if no one is subscribed to it. For example your communicator can start emitting items when no on is listening to it.

Comment: That is true but that can handle inside the communicator class. You can check whether some is subscribe it or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return an `Observable<Boolean>` from your `act` method. Then you can call `onCompleted` on `Subscriber` which will be your consuming class.

Code:

```
 class Builder {
   public Observable<Boolean> act() {
      return Observable<Boolean>.create {
        public void call(final Subscriber subscriber) {
         processRunner.runAsync(new ProcessRunner.ProcessResultHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(int result) {
                subscriber.onNext(true);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        });
       }
      }
   }
 }
```

Consuming Class:

```
     builder.act().subscribe({
        void onNext(boolean status) {}
        void onCompleted() { // finished }
      })
```

Code Not tested. There might be syntax errors.